# Getting disk sector size without raw filesystem permission

Tags: linux, posix, ioctl

I'm trying to get the sector size, specifically so I can correctly size the buffer for reading/writing with O_DIRECT.

The following code works when my app's run as root:

```
int fd = open("/dev/xvda1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
size_t blockSize;
int rc = ioctl(fd, BLKSSZGET, &blockSize);
```

How can I get the sector size without it being run as root?

Comment: Are you reading (with `O_DIRECT`) the raw partition, or some file on a filesystem in it?

Comment: Why are you asking? Are you seeking the best IO performance, or for some other reasons?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm reading and writing to files, and using O_DIRECT for performance as I'm only ever reading or writing a randomly positioned 512 byte chunk.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Linux manpage for open():

> In Linux alignment restrictions vary by file system and kernel version and might be absent entirely.  However there is currently no file system-independent interface for an application to discover these restrictions for a given file or  file  system. Some file systems provide their own interfaces for doing so, for example the XFS_IOC_DIOINFO operation in xfsctl(3).

So it looks like you may be able to obtain this information using xfsctl()... if you are using xfs.

Since your underlying block device is a Xen virtual block device and there might be any number of layers below that (LVM, dm-crypt, another filesystem, etc...) I'm not sure how meaningful all of this will really be for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [stat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) and related syscall (perhaps on some particular file), then use the `st_blksize` field. However this would give a file-system related blocksize, not the size of the sector as preferred by the hardware. But for `O_DIRECT` input (from a file on filesystem!) that `st_blocksize` might be more relevant.

Otherwise, I would suggest a power-of-two size, perhaps 8Kbytes or 64Kbytes, as the size of your `O_DIRECT`-ed reads (and you may want to align your read buffer to the page size, usually 4Kbytes).